# Create a Function which returns -1 for empty matrix, 0 for scalar, 1 for vector, 2 for none of these

Tags: matlab

I am not allowed to use `isempty`, `isscalar`, or `isvector`.

**My code is :**

```
 function a = classify(x)
 b = sum(x(:));
 c = sum(b);
 if c == 0
    a = -1;
 elseif length(x) == 1
        a = 0;
 elseif length(x) > 1
        a = 1;
 else
      a = 2;
 end
```

I am getting error with input :

```
 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Output for above input is 1

My Auto grader is giving the following error:

> Feedback: Your function made an error for argument(s) `[0 1 0 0 0 1 1;1 0 0 1 1 0 0;1 1 0 0 1 1 1;0 1 1 1 1 1 0;0 1 0 1 0 1 0;1 0 0 1 1 1 1;0 1 0 0 0 0 1]`
>       Your solution is *not* correct.

Comment: the sum of the array [-1, 1] is zero, but the array is not empty. This seems like homework, so I won't write the code for you, but I'll give you suggestions: think what empty matrix, scalar, vector etc. mean, and then use the `size` function.

Comment: Moshen you are right but i don't know how to check for empty matrix without isempty function.  Little help please..

Comment: To check for empty matrix I have tried this :
 [m,n] = size(x);
 d = m * n;
if d == 0
    a = -1;

but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Is the function `any` allowed? If so, you can use it to great effects.

Comment: here is my new code:


function a = classify(x)
[m,n] = size(x);
d = m * n;
 if d == 0
     a = -1;
 elseif d == 1
     a = 0;
 elseif d > 1
     a = 1;
 else
     a = 2;
 end

I thinks there is nothing wrong in it. Please tell me if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yes, any is allowed but i will try any if above code is wrong.

Comment: @ManroopSingh make the edits to your post, it's much easier for readers to parse than trying to read it in the comments

Comment: Hola!!     Solved. Thanks friends.

Comment: what if the input is a string or cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use `size`, then a possible solution is

```
function R = classify(data)
  S = size(data);
  if any(S == 0) % There is at least one dimension that is zero
    R = -1;
  elseif all(S == 1) % All dimensions are equal to 1
    R = 0;
  elseif sum(~(S == 1)) == 1 % There is exactly one dimension that contains more than 1 element
    R = 1;
  else % There are more than 1 dimensions with more than 1 element
    R = 2;
  end
end
```

Comment: You could greatly simplify this; in particular, `return` isn't really needed here. Also, what if `data` is an N-array with N > 2? Your code doesn't cover this case.

Comment: Indeed, the return statement is not required if you put the R=2 in an else block. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by N-array.

Comment: *[...] the return statement is not required if you put the R=2 in an else block*. Yes, that would make more sense. By N-array, I mean an array with N dimensions. In MATLAB, arrays are at least 2D, but you can also have higher-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Jubobs: Changed my answer to take all dimensions into account. I have also removed the return statement - though I think this is just a question of style as in terms of performance both are the same.

Comment: That's better, but, for better readability, you should use at least two spaces per indent. You could also replace `prod(S) == 0` by `any(S == 0)`, and `prod(S) == 1` by `all(S == 1)`; that would be easier to read and probably a bit (?) more efficient. As for the vector case, what the OP means by "vector" is unclear. According to MATLAB's `isvector` function, a vector is an array of the size `[1,n]` or `[n,1]`, where is a nonnegative integer (which means that n=0 is allowed).

Comment: You're right, using `any` and `all` makes things a bit cleaner - adjusted accordingly. As for the question how you define a vector, I think it's a question of definition. I would not call an N-array with a dimension equal to zero a vector, while I would say that a matrix with a size of [1, 1, N] is also a vector.

Comment: *I would say that a matrix with a size of [1, 1, N] is also a vector.* Yes; based on the specs of the OP's assignment, I think that makes sense. Finally, you can also drop the parens around the each condition; they're not needed.

Comment: @Jubobs, i was unaware of 'any' function. It solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ManroopSingh If Tamás's answer solved your problem, consider accepting it.